# ssh with keys work on one Ubuntu box bot not on another Ubuntu box

Tags: ssh

This is driving me nuts :)

I'm trying to ssh from a Synology diskstation to a Ubuntu server. I've created a keypair on the Synology box:

```
ssh-keygen -v -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2 -P ""
```

and copied the ~/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2.pub from the Synology box to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the Ubuntu box.

It works just fine.

Now, I did the exact same things for/on the other Ubuntu box, but ssh keeps prompting me for a password:

why???

```
backupsvc@NAS9:~/.ssh$ ssh rsyncuser@ubuntubox2 -i /var/services/homes/backupsvc/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2 -v
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Connecting to ubuntubox2 [10.0.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/backupsvc/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2 type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/backupsvc/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ubuntubox2:22 as 'rsyncuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dNwmsFmQw2apTUYZWTBy6G0pd9hVA+OKS/Q5G1bmlfI
debug1: Host 'ubuntubox2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/services/homes/backupsvc/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/services/homes/backupsvc/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
rsyncuser@ubuntubox2's password:
```

Comment: Did you read the Troubleshooting section from the [help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) ?

Comment: on same machine where you ran above command issue  echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK     you should see something like /tmp/ssh-fSVtTf9an4F5/agent.2233   if instead you see something like /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh   then add following to beginning like   SSH_AUTH_SOCK=''  ssh rsyncuser@ubuntubox2 -i /var/services/homes/backupsvc/.ssh/backup-ubuntubox2 -v

Comment: @RoVo: Yes. Everything looks good
ScottStensland: echo  $SSH_AUTH_SOCK returns an empty string.

Comment: @RoVo: Found the culprit in the Troubleshooting section. Owner and group was set incorrectly on the home folder ~/
I changed the owner:

sudo chown rsyncuser .

and it worked. I was let to the conclusion by the error msg: "Permission denied, please try again."

Comment: Great. You can answer your own question so that it might help others =)